# Ошибка при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

При запуске приложения выводит ошибку:

> В приложении "Saint switcher" произошла ошибка

В чем может быть ошибка? Вылетает на этом месте: `holycrap.setAdapter(adapter);`

Вот код полностью

```
package com.example.saintswitcher;

import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView holycrap;
    final String[] a_che = new String[] {
            "Тапочки", "Ластики", "Кошки", "Литераторы", "Стринги",
            "Томат", "Еда", "Стринги", "Лошадь на горе", "Фалопиева труба",
            "Иттрий", "Стринги", "Двшка"            
          };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                holycrap = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a_che);
        holycrap.setAdapter(adapter);


        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(holycrap);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы выкинули нерелевантную часть, а? И сказали, в какой процедуре и какой строке вылетает, а то у нас единственный телепат не подтянулся пока.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, holycrap не найден. Проверьте, что в layout'е есть такой элемент и что у него такой id, как в коде.